# How to save parse push notification message in local storage sencha touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am recieving push notification on my android device but stuck to get it saved using any plugin or some JS code.

Following is the code I have modified in Activity onCreate

```
Parse.initialize(this, "2dkgSPO0Pklpuo3yVjY8KeUQKtNWwpitTFMlMdHF", "O4ViBkcJRo9MrCeiKF49czzVrc7htMcYfdySKFTF");
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MyPhoneGapActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

Following are the changes I have done in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
     <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver> // in application tag
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a store that uses local storage, then add a model when you get a push and sync the store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Notification', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            // notification fields
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'notifications'
        }
    }
});    

Ext.define('MyApp.store.Notification', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'MyApp.store.Notification',
        autoSync: true,
        autoLoad: true
    }
});


receiveNotification: function(notif)
{
    var store = Ext.getStore('Notifications'), 
        record = //create your model from notif

    store.sync();
}
```

Comment: There is no issue with store and model creation but the issue is that how to get this function called when a notification is received. I am currently using Parse and PhoneGap for receiving push notifications

Comment: So are you actually receiving the notifications?  If so, post your code for that.

Comment: Added code in question. have a look please and let me know that how should I receive intent of notification.